# Are all administration functions for the channel joining, chaincode installing/upgrading removed from fabric-network / fabric-common?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm preparing that my client server using the old v1.4 `fabric-client` SDK to the new v2.1 `fabric-network` and `fabric-common` SDK. In my old server, I built many administration functions such as;

- creating channels
- joining peers to channels
- updating channel configs such as batchSize
- instantiating/upgrading chaincodes

However, I cannot find any APIs from `fabric-network` or `fabric-common` to do these administration things. For example, there is no `installChaincode` function from `Client` class in `fabric-common`.

How can I implement these administration operations using the v2.1 `fabric-network` and `fabric-common` SDK? Or, should I think another way such as using `peer` CLI (which I never want to do) rather than implementing the administration server to control the Hyperledger Fabric network?

If SDKs of other languages such as Golang or Java have such APIs, then let me know please. I'm okay to develop the administration server using other languages than JavaScript, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked about it and I got an answer that all admin APIs had been removed from all SDK including node, Java, etc. This is a confirmed decision, so, at this point, finding other options such as using CLI is a way to do some admin stuff.